# mupdf-tools don't install mudraw

Tags: mupdf

When i try to install mupdf-tools, it won't install mudraw.
If i type in terminal "dpkg -L mupdf-tools" i get the following output:
/.

/usr

/usr/share

/usr/share/doc

/usr/share/doc/mupdf-tools

/usr/share/doc/mupdf-tools/README

/usr/share/doc/mupdf-tools/copyright

/usr/share/doc/mupdf-tools/changelog.Debian.gz

/usr/share/man

/usr/share/man/man1

/usr/share/man/man1/mutool.1.gz

/usr/bin

/usr/bin/mutool

As can be seen, mudraw don't appear in the list.
How can i fix this so i will have mudraw?
I'm using ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not said which version of ubuntu or which version of the mupdf-tools package.

Ubuntu 15.10 (Wily) contains mupdf-tools package 1.7-1, and that contains mudraw:

```
# dpkg -l mupdf-tools
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                         Version             Architecture        Description
+++-============================-===================-===================-=============================================================
ii  mupdf-tools                  1.7-1               i386                commmand line tools for the MuPDF viewer

# dpkg -L mupdf-tools
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/mupdf-tools
/usr/share/doc/mupdf-tools/README
/usr/share/doc/mupdf-tools/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/mupdf-tools/copyright
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/mudraw.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mutool.1.gz
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/mutool
/usr/bin/mudraw
```

For mupdf 1.8 or later, mudraw is now invoked via 'mutool draw' and there is no separate mudraw binary.

Comment: thanks for your response, i had version 1.8, changed to 1.7 and it works now.

Comment: Ah, if you are using 1.8, mudraw is now invoked by 'mutool draw'.

Answer (score 0):

Because compatibility issue, I was to mantain the mudraw command temporally in Ubuntu 17.04.

My solution: create a bash file named "mudraw" that performs "mutool draw":

```
$ echo '#!/bin/sh' >> mudraw
$ echo 'mutool draw "$@"' >> mudraw
$ chmod +755 mudraw
$ sudo mv mudraw /usr/bin
$ mudraw -v
```